# how to parse xml in from a WinHttp.WinHttpRequest object?

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing, winhttprequest

I have a standalone VBScript which connects to server and gets the response text(as XML) in a WinHttpRequest object. Now, my question is how do I parse the XML content in it. When I post a request(strPostData) I need to parse the response XML. What I am using below is not working as I'm unable to print output on the console. I'm able to output the ResponseText though. But I'm unable to parse it.

```
  Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
  objWinHttp.Send(strPostData)
  objWinHttp.WaitForResponse()

    If objWinHttp.Status = "200" Then
        GetDataFromURL = objWinHttp.ResponseText
        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        xmlDoc.loadXML(GetDataFromURL)
        Set ops = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Response\Status").item(0).text


      WScript.Echo "Output is: " & ops
      WScript.Echo "Message: " & GetDataFromURL
      Msgbox GeteDataFromURL
      WScript.Quit(0)
```

Here is the XML to be parsed:

```
<RCTRequest>
    <Response>
       <Name>aaa</Name>
       <Status>44</Status>
    </Response>
</RCTRequest>
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I'm sorry, when i said message I meant the ResponseText. I changed the question now

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath

```
  Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
  xmlDoc.async = false
  xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"      
  xmlDoc.loadXML(GetDataFromURL)
  Set ops =xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/RCTRequest/Response/Status")
  WScript.Echo "Output is: " &  (ops.text)
  WScript.Echo "Message: " & GetDataFromURL
  Msgbox GeteDataFromURL
  WScript.Quit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get "runtime error: Object required" error. It is caused by the line

```
Set ops = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Response\Status").item(0).text
```

Just remove `set` from the beginning of that line.

Comment: I'm sorry, when i said message I meant the ResponseText. I changed the question now

Comment: I asked for the symptoms of the fact that you are unable to print output to the console. In the meantime I've tried to parse your XML and `Set ops = ` gave me "Object required" error, so I posted my answer.

Comment: I do not get any error. The output is just not printed on console

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using XMLDOM.  Check out my article [Reading XML Files in WSH](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Reading-XML-Files-in-WSH/) for examples on how to parse specific data from an XML input.

Answer (score 0):

```
strFile = "inp.xml"
Set objFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
set xmlDoc=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.load(strFile)
For each x in xmlDoc.documentElement.attributes
  WScript.Echo x.nodeName, x.text
Next

set xmlCol = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes
For Each Elem In xmlCol 
 If StrComp(Elem.nodeName, "p") = 0 Then
  set nestedChild = Elem.childNodes

  For Each node In nestedChild 
    If StrComp(node.nodeName, "XYZ") = 0 Then
      WScript.Echo Elem.xml
      set a = objFS.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", true)
      a.WriteLine(Elem.xml)
      a.Close()
    End If
  Next

 End If
Next
```